# php str_replace only replacing the 1st value in the needle array

Tags: php, str-replace

I have been using this function for some time now but this is the 1st time I am having this weird trouble with PHP's `str_replace` function. Here is my code...

```
$e2p_perline = explode(',', $e2p_wrd_rplc);

        $e2p_words = array();
        $e2p_words_2b = array();
        $e2p_loopcounter = 0;

        foreach($e2p_perline as $line){

            $e2p_line_words = explode('-', $line);
            $e2p_words[$e2p_loopcounter] = $e2p_line_words[0];
            $e2p_words_2b[$e2p_loopcounter] = $e2p_line_words[1];

            $e2p_loopcounter++;
        }

$e2p_message = str_replace($e2p_words, $e2p_words_2b, $e2p_message);
```

`$e2p_wrd_rplc` is a string loaded from the database using get_option() function of wordpress.  String data in this format `c*sh-cash, v*gra-viagra, s3x-sex,....`

`$e2p_words` is an array filled with the words to be replaced and `$e2p_words_2b` is an array filled with replacement words.

Lets suppose we have

`e2p_words` is (c*sh, v*agra, s3x)

`e2p_words_2b` is (cash, viagra, sex)

Now when I run this, only the 1st word `c*sh` is replaced with `cash`. Rest of the `e2p_words` occurrences in `e2p_message` stay the same.

I am getting no errors or warnings either.

Comment: please post the relevant code you're executing

Comment: I have edited the original post to add the extra bit of code to show how the arrays getting data

Answer (score 2):

**This works for me :**

```
<?php

$e2p_words = array("c*sh", "v*agra", "s3x");
$e2p_words_2b = array("cash", "viagra", "sex");

$e2p_message = "Get a v*agra, or you'll have to pay c*sh for some real s3x.";

$e2p_message = str_replace($e2p_words, $e2p_words_2b, $e2p_message);

echo $e2p_message;

?>
```

**Output :**

```
Get a viagra, or you'll have to pay cash for some real sex.
```

Comment: Yes it works like that but I am getting values in those arrays from a mysql database. I thought those values might not be loading properly into the array so I used `print_r` and they were all there.

Comment: @Lafanter Could you edit your initial question and add : 1) HOW you're getting your values, 2) Your value arrays ?

Comment: hmmm ... no answers ? any one ? any clue ?

Comment: @Lafanter If you do answer **my** last question, then helping you might be easier...

Comment: @ Dr.Kameleon, hey thanks for responding. I updated my original post with the extra bit of code you were asking for on the same day.

Comment: still waiting... any thing ? any one ?